# Fundamental Group and DeRahm Cohomology from Group of Covering Transformations

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Old qual problem here, test tomorrow in topology and we barely got to DeRahm Cohomology so I'm not sure how to do this.

> Let $G$ be the group of transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by
>   \begin{align} A(x,y,z)&=(x+1,y,z)\\
> B(x,y,z)&=(x,y+1,z)\\
> C(x,y,z)&=(x+y,y,z+1). \end{align} Assume that $M=\mathbb{R}^3/G$ is a
>   three-manifold.
>
> a. Determine $\pi_1(M)$ up to isomorphism by giving a presentation
>   with generators and relations. (*note* the relations will involve only
>   commutators of generators)
>
> b. Determine $H_{DR}^1(M)$ up to isomorphism and give closed one-forms
>   whose cohomology classes are a basis of $H_{DR}^1(M)$.

Here's all I've got:

We know that $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{R}^3$ so $\pi_1(M)=G$, but I'm not sure how to write $G$.

When we have $G$, we know that $H_{DR}^1(X)=Hom(H_1(X),\mathbb{R})$ where $H_1(X)$ is $\pi_1(X)$ abelianized. I'm also not sure how to find the 1-forms giving a basis.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simple computations, one checks $AB=BA$, $AC=CA$, $CB=BCA$ is a presentation. So in the abelianization $A=1$, $BC=CB$ the abelianized group is $\bf Z^2$.

Note that  $dy, dz$ are invariant by $G$ and form a base for the de Rham co-homology

Comment: One last thing- how do I check that dx,dy are invariant by G?

Comment: $dx$ is not invariant but $dz$ and $dy$ are. For $z\circ A= z= z\circ B, z\circ C=z+1$, so $A^*dz=dz, B^*dz=dz, C^*dz=dz$ ; and the same sort of computations with $dy$

Comment: Sorry I meant dy, dz. Thank you. It is all clear now. My final is in a couple hours and we really rushed through that last chapter because we were running behind. Thank you for your help!